# Can't generate accurate result because of weird way someone entered data (1 12 13)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm working with an ad booking system, not built by myself. For each row in the ads table, there can be multiple sizes. Each size is a reference ID to another table. That's fine.

But it's stored like this (when I write space, that's an actual space):

1(space)(space)(space)12(space)

1(space)(space)(space)(space)(space)

2(space)(space)25(space)1

Looks like this:

1   12

1

2  25 1

So, of course, when I do a query like this:

```
$this->db->get_where('online_ads', array('submitted >=' => '1314887098', 'submitted <=' => '1317673118', 'size' => '1'));
```

I get anything with a 1 in it. I tried this:

```
$this->db->like('size', '1')->get_where('online_ads', array('submitted >=' => '1314887098', 'submitted <=' => '1317673118'));
```

But it still doesn't give me accurate results. I also tried FIND_IN_SET but that only works with commas.

How can I find out how many 1s, how many 2s, how many 12s, etc. there are stored without it giving me anything with a 1 in it or a 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to use more advanced pattern matching, like [regexp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp). If you want only things starting with "1 ", something like `RLIKE "^1 "` should work, I think.

Comment: You could also use [[:blank:]] as character class... In case, space are tab and other possible stuff :)